# How can I intercept the pressing of multiply (*) key?

Tags: c++, qt, qkeyevent

I'm working on a calculator application that has a keyboard for input: (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,-,+,/,*,.,(,),).

Firstly, I tried just to implement `keyPressEvent` method like this:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* ev)
{
    QString CurrentLabel_disp = ui->label->text();
    QString KeyPressed;

    if (ev->key() == Qt::Key_0)
        KeyPressed = "0";
    else if (ev->key() == Qt::Key_1)
        KeyPressed = "1";
...    

    else if (ev->key() == Qt::Key_Plus)
        KeyPressed = "+";
    else if (ev->key() == Qt::Key_Minus)
        KeyPressed = "-";
    else if (ev->key() == Qt::Key_Slash)
        KeyPressed = "/";
    else if (ev->key() == Qt::Key_multiply)
        KeyPressed = "*";
}
```

Then I decided to reimplement `bool eventFilter()` and use `installEventFilter(this)` method instead of `keyPressEvent`:

```cpp
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){
    if(obj==this && event->type()==QEvent::KeyPress){
        QKeyEvent* keyEvent=static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        QString KeyPressed;
        switch (keyEvent->key()) {
        case Qt::Key_0:
             KeyPressed="0";VisualItem_key_pressed(KeyPressed);return true;
        case Qt::Key_1:
             KeyPressed="1";VisualItem_key_pressed(KeyPressed);return true;

...       

        case Qt::Key_Plus:
             KeyPressed="+";VisualItem_key_pressed(KeyPressed);return true;
        case Qt::Key_Minus:
             KeyPressed="-";VisualItem_key_pressed(KeyPressed);return true;
        case Qt::Key_Slash:
             KeyPressed="/";VisualItem_key_pressed(KeyPressed);return true;
        case Qt::Key_multiply:
             KeyPressed="*";VisualItem_key_pressed(KeyPressed);return true;
        }
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj,event);
}
```

But in the first and second cases, multiply key (<kbd>*</kbd>) was not working, unlike the other keys.

So the program doesn't associate pressing (<kbd>*</kbd>) key on the Numpad, or pressing (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>) with `case Qt::Key_multiply`.

Maybe the problem is in `Qt::Key_multiply`, because I really don't know how the Numpad decimal separator (<kbd>.</kbd>) and multiply (<kbd>*</kbd>) symbols are called in Qt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this: [`Qt::Key_Asterisk`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#Key-enum).